# How do you invoke a 'Enter' keypress with webkitbrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, webkit, browser

I am working on a program that will make me to be able to post message in a chatbox on a website without doing the posting manually. I have this code to put the text into the `textbox`:

```
message = txtMessage.Text;
foreach(Node txt in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
{
    if(((Element)txt).GetAttribute("Class") == "chat_input")
    {
        ((Element)txt).Focus();
        ((Element)txt).TextContent = message;
    }
}
```

Website code is:

```
<textarea class="chat_input">

    Enter text for chat here

</textarea>
```

All it has a textbox, and not a post button. It posts the message when you press enter. What I need now, is some code for invoking an enter keypress.

Does anyone know how to do that? And is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

More info at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

All the best!